Highcharter - remove border from bars in plot
I want to remove a white border that's appearing around bars in a clustered bar chart plotted with Highcharter.
Following Highcharts documentation this requires appending a borderColor variable in the plotOptions argument.
Porting to Highcharter as follows does not produce any effect.
hc_plotOptions(series = list(pointWidth = 15), style = list(borderColor = '#2ECC71')) 

Has any one tried this successfully, am I missing something?

Saw it as soon as I posted.
hc_plotOptions(series = list(pointWidth = 15, borderColor = '#2ECC71'))

This however gives the one colour outline to all bars, so to remove just leave borderColor blank.
hc_plotOptions(series = list(pointWidth = 15, borderColor = ''))

